# Как реализовать работу с дампом базы данных в C++

Tags: c++

В базе данных у каждой строки есть свой "Code". Моей задачей является поиск введённого пользователем значения и вывод строки, которой соответствует данный Code. Как реализуется поиск? У меня считывается только первая строка базы. Ниже прикрепляю свой код.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

char text[500];

ifstream file("census.csv");
if (!file.is_open())
    cout << "Error 404! File is not found!" << endl;
else
    file >> text;
cout << text << endl;

file.getline (text, 50000);
cout << text << endl;
file.close();

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Сам файл]

Comment: Называть csv-файл базой данных, наверное, слишком громко)

Comment: У вас ровно один `file.getline` в коде. Поэтому вы читаете ровно одну строку.

Comment: то есть можно реализовать через цикл for?

Comment: Можно через for, можно через while, можно и с goto на худой конец (не надо)

Comment: А как реализовать поиск именно по "Code"'?

Comment: Ну, это нужно парсить csv. В простых случаях можно просто резать по запятой, но в общем случае, нужно смотреть на строковые литералы в кавычках(в них могут быть запятые, которые не делят строку), экранирование. Рекомендую найти готовое решение для разбора csv

Comment: думаю, в данном случае даже парсер csv не нужен - можно просто по началу смотреть до запятой. Но даже сам парсер написать в данном случае - простое дело